# App redirected to another link instead of page tab app.

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to send a request to a friend with the Javascript SDK from a **Page Tab App**. The code is as shown below.

```
 function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
  }
```

The user receives the request but is redirect to somewhere else. They are redirected to

http://www.facebook.com/**apps**/application.php?id=537700179592094

instead of:

http://www.facebook.com/**pages**/****/139287799553506?sk=app_537700179592094

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior or the request feature.  For your situation You will need to build a separate page and have your canvas app point there to handle the necessary redirect to the tab app.

The reason for this is because an application can be installed on any number of pages.  How is Facebook to know what installation it would need direct a user to after accepting a request.  But every app only has one canvas page.